# How to retrieve number of results of MySQL result in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$sql = 'select ...';

$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mysql_num_rows()`](http://de.php.net/mysql_num_rows)

> Retrieves the number of rows from a
>   result set. This command is only valid
>   for statements like SELECT or SHOW
>   that return an actual result set. To
>   retrieve the number of rows affected
>   by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE
>   query, use mysql_affected_rows().